# How to change bg image for mobile and desktop with react-parallax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using react-parallax (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-parallax) and I would like to use a different bg image for desktop and mobile. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you would need to use a media query hook, to be able to conditionally render another image when your screen size is below certain pixels. see this: https://github.com/streamich/use-media

Comment: @jean182 Thanks for the suggestion, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to implement media queries as in the css sample below.
With media queries you can wrap css lines that will only apply if the certain rules stated within the media queries do apply. In this case the screen width.

```css
/* background image for devices with 480px or below */
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      background-image: url("");
      background-color: blue;
      
    }
}

/* background image for devices with 481px or above */
@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    body {
      background-image: url("");
      background-color: red;
    }
}
```